# updates.sh - Command Not Found - Arch linux

Tags: shell, arch-linux, data-recovery, binary, restore

I installed Archlabs 1 month later, today I noticed bin folder in `~` directory and Deleted it. After Reboot This errors Came out in polybar

`/bin/sh: updates.sh: command not foun`

And

`/bin/sh: check-network: command not found`

I remember thad there was 4 folders int that bin folder which i deleted.
can you help me to restore it or get rid of this errors?

P.s also `alt+f1` and win key not working it says

`failed to execute child process "rofi_run" ( No Such file or directory )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're probably getting these errors is because the ~/bin folder contains programs added to your $PATH, via ~/.profile.

I recommend making a new user on the machine, and copy all of the contents of their ~/bin directory to a ~/bin directory in your user directory.

Comment: Thanks @CoderSiri very much. you saved me ton of time